# java - Как принимать ввод с консоли и при этом не усыпляя другие потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Мне надо ожидать вывод с консоли в одном потоке и обновлять окно в другом.

Java 21

Пример кода:

```java
package com.example.test;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainFile extends Application {
    public static boolean ExitUpdate = false;
    public static Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX!");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Создаем JavaFX окно
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        update(root, 0);
    }
    public void update(StackPane root, int c) {
        if (c > 1) {
            c = 0;
        }
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                root.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(100,100, Color.BLUE));
                break;
            case 1:
                root.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(110,110, Color.RED));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("err");
        }

        int sendc = c+1;
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        update(root, sendc);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        Timer start = new Timer("test");
        start.schedule(timerTask, 1000L);
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

К примеру как тут сделать ожидание ввода, чтобы квадраты не переставали появляться.

Если это невозможно, то какую альтернативу можно использовать?

Comment: По-моему, вы полностью изменили вопрос, отредактировав его, а так делать точно не нужно. Тем более, что вам уже был дан ответ на оригинал вопроса. Верните всё как было, а если возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно.

Comment: хорошо, задам новый вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью ExecutorService, внутри него отправлять сообщение в Fx-поток через Platform.runLater()

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainFile extends Application {


    private static Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX!");

    private  final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    executor.submit(() -> {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Press Enter to continue...");
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            if(s != null && !s.trim().isEmpty() && s.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> update(root, Integer.parseInt(s)));
            }
        }
    });

    update(root, 0);
}

public void update(StackPane root, int c) {
    if (c > 1) {
        c = 0;
    }

    switch (c) {
        case 0:
            root.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLUE));
            break;
        case 1:
            root.getChildren().addAll(new Rectangle(110, 110, Color.RED));
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("err");
    }

    int sendc = c + 1;
    executor.submit(() -> update(root, sendc));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Вы нейросетью код генерировали? Квадраты теперь не меняют цвета.

Comment: код рабочий будьте уверены, по Вашему свичу цвет меняется

Comment: может быть в Platform.runLater(() -> update(root, Integer.parseInt(s))); Вы передаете 0 вместо s?

Comment: Я полностью скопировал ваш код и он заработал не правильно.

Comment: А как он должен работать правильно? На начальном экране по центру окна у Вас синий квадрат, при вводе 1 квадрат становится красным, при вводе 0, он снова становится синим, но в красной рамке т.к. у вас именно так задан size. В Ваш код я добавил ExecutorService, внутри которого читается сканнером строка ввода, проверяется, что это число и передается в метод update, который будет вызван в Fx-потоке со следующего такта процессора. Код разумеется не продуктовый, но формат и не подразумевает, что я Вам дам код, который бы приняли в продакшн

Comment: я в вопросе указал, что мне нужно сделать так, чтобы они сами менялись раз в секунду и при этом принимался ввод одновременно.